# Where do the words sholom bayis come from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, home-house, shalom-peace

I hear people speak of the need for *sholom bayis*.

1a) Where do the words come from?

1b) Where does the concept come from?

Comment: Kapital 30 in tehilim

Comment: @DovidBenizri Do you mean a different kapital?

Comment: Off topic?????????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

וַאֲמַרְתֶּם כֹּה לֶחָי וְאַתָּה שָׁלוֹם וּבֵיתְךָ שָׁלוֹם וְכֹל אֲשֶׁר-לְךָ שָׁלוֹם: - שמואל א כה:ו

"and thus ye shall say: All hail! and peace be both unto thee, and peace be to thy house, and peace be unto all that thou hast." - Samuel 2:25:6

אמר רבא: פשיטא לי נר ביתו ונר חנוכה נר ביתו עדיף משום שלום ביתו; נר ביתו וקידוש היום נר ביתו עדיף משום שלום ביתו...- שבת כג ב

Raba said: It's obvious to me that, between the lamp of the house and the lamp of Hannukah, the lamp of the house is more important because of peace in his home; between the lamp of the house and the sacntification of the day, the lamp of the house is more important because of peace in his home...
 - Talmud Shabbat 23b