# How did the term "Shalom Bayit" come to mean "matrimonial harmony"?

Tags: etymology, shalom-bayit

A follow up to [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/where-do-the-words-sholom-bayis-come-from) :

The answer there (so far), addresses the source of the term, in general and cites Talmud Shabbat which seems to address the importance of lighting Shabbat candles. I believe that the Talmud explains either there or somewhere else that the "peace" created in the house is that by having light, people in the household won't trip over each other in the dark.

The term "Shalom Bayit", now, seems to mean "matrimonial harmony" - i.e. peace and calm between husband and wife. This definition does not seem to emanate from the Talmud - at least not from the location cited.

Where, when and how did this definition arise?

Answer (score 3):

The [Rashash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Strashun) on Rashi there ([Shabbos 23b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&pgnum=787) d.h. *mishum shalom beiso*) explains the reference to mean marital harmony and connects it to the *mishnah* in *bameh madlikin* about the wife lighting the *ner shabbos* and the fact that *beiso* is used to refer to a wife, *ayin sham*.

> **משום שלום ביתו.** ופירש''י שב''ב מצטערין. לכאורה מאי איריא ב''ב אף הוא בעצמו נמי יצטער. ואולי יכוון רבא במלת ביתו על אשתו וכדלקמן
>   (https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.10),
>    ור''ל משום דאיתא לקמן על ג''ע נשים מתות כו' ובהדלקת הנר
>   (https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31b.9),
>   לכן אם לא תדליק אתיא לאנצויי עמו.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you referred to a commentary ON the Rash"i. Can you provide a link to this?

Comment: @DanF http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&pgnum=787

Comment: Thank you. I'm unfamiliar with this commentary. I gather that it is in the back of each Masechta? I must have an "older" Gemarah version at home. What, exactly, is this commentary?

Comment: Related (the Rashis) https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Shabbat.23b.3.2 and https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Shabbat.25b.5.1