# stubbing your toe and peace with you wife, what is the connection

Tags: sources-mekorot, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, candle-lighting, shalom-bayit

one of the reasons for lighting shabbos candles is "peace in the home"

shulchan aurch harav [263.1](http://www.chabad.org/3447046/) explains "peace in the home" that not to stub you foot on wood or stone

the [mishna torah megila 4](http://www.chabad.org/952009/):14 seems to hint that "peace in the home" is peace between husband and wife,
and it is used as a saying for this until today

is there a connection between these to?
please explain
sources appreciated

---

related
[Where do the words sholom bayis come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56152/5120)
[How did the term "Shalom Bayit" come to mean "matrimonial harmony"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56159/5120)

---

related end of halacha 5 here http://www.chabad.org/3447016/
and https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.250.5/

Comment: Thats Mishn**eh** Torah, as in Deut. 17:18.

Comment: When you stub your toe, you get unhappy.  (Or ח"ו if you trip, which could also be what the Shulchan Aruch Harav means, you could break your leg and get even more unhappy.)  This makes tensions build.  "Why did you put that chair there, you know I always trip over it??!!"  Then they could potentially get upset at each other over other minor things.  This isn't a stretch, I can easily imagine it happening.  Part of the solution is they should be more calm, but removing little things that can make people upset goes a long way.

Comment: @Heshy very nice , a source will make it an **accept**able  answer

Comment: @Heshy it seem the Rashash quoted in this answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56164/5120 says that he gets unhappy with her not because she put the chair but because she did not light the candles

Comment: @hazoriz I can imagine either happening, and either one is bad.  Shalom bayis is not a list of bad things that the husband and wife should avoid.  Any time they're upset with each other it's bad.

Comment: @Heshy i just read it again and it seems the problem is that his wife is getting upset because she did not light them and woman dye because of that, so if she will not light them she will argue with him, i am not so good with reading i hope someone will correct me: 
משום שלום ביתו. ופירש''י שב''ב מצטערין. לכאורה מאי איריא ב''ב אף הוא בעצמו נמי יצטער. ואולי יכוון רבא במלת ביתו על אשתו וכדלקמן
(https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.10),
ור''ל משום דאיתא לקמן על ג''ע נשים מתות כו' ובהדלקת הנר
(https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31b.9),
לכן אם לא תדליק אתיא לאנצויי עמו.

Comment: @hazoriz There are so many reasons why not lighting candles can lead to fighting, they're not mutually exclusive.  If you try to make shalom bayis into a checklist, you won't succeed.

Comment: @Heshy if this is what you call it I agree, but if you make a paradigm shift a list of obligations might help the peace once you're not obligated to I can't be upset about

Comment: @hazoriz I don't think talking about shalom bayis in terms of "obligated" and "can't be upset" is constructive.  (Except for things that we are obligated to do, like lighting candles, which is a special mitzva miderabbanan.)  The husband and wife are BOTH obligated to keep shalom bayis, which means not doing things that will make the other upset, and not getting upset.  If one of them gets upset, they have failed, and they should BOTH work on making it better.

Comment: @Heshy prove it, I see it as  the obligation to light candles and to have peace is not an obligation to the other party but to Hashem , it is not the other party's business my obligations to Hashem, but some things are obligations to the other party if those are full filled nothing to be upset about

Comment: @hazoriz you may be right in principle, but talking about peace in terms of individual responsibilities does not help peace, in practice.  Maybe one of them is more at fault, but they will be more able to fix it if they don't think about that.  For example see Rashi Pirkei Avos 1:12 (not the part about the husband and wife, the part about the two people fighting).

Comment: @Heshy Rabbi Menshe Kline claims most people do not know there obligations , how can they see themselves as wrong if they have know clue what is right (nesive 7 here http://www.tshuvos.com/pdf/beisrachel.pdf (page 29)

Comment: @hazoriz Yes, that's the absolute minimum requirement of a marriage.  Just because you do the bare minimum doesn't mean you have shalom bayis.

Comment: @Heshy if the other party does the minimum I do not have any right to be upset, complain or....

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56159/759

Comment: @DoubleAA it is linked to in the end of the OP

Comment: @Heshy related end of halacha 5 here http://www.chabad.org/3447016/ and https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.250.5/

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.
The Prisha in siman 263 s"k 2 quotes the Beis Yosef at the end of the siman who says that candles arouse feelings of joy and this is based on the gemorah in Shabbos 25a which quotes a verse from Eichah (Lamentations) 3:17- 
וַתִּזְנַ֧ח מִשָּׁל֛וֹם נַפְשִׁ֖י
 -"And my soul is far removed from peace"  and the gemorah says that this verse is referring to shabbos canles and the Ra"n  explains that this is because the people in the house don't enjoy (suffering) being in the dark.
The Beis Yosef says that the more light there is the more Shalom Bayis and joy there will be because of the light in all the corners of the house.

(I don't know if this is allowed on this website but The Huffington post had an article about this on 02/24/2014 called "How The Light In A Room Could Affect Your Emotions").

Comment: Hi user155551. [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for the answer. I suggest that you [edit your profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a more meaningful name!